# Jackson XmlMapper serialize nested object @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true) doesn't work correctly

Tags: xml, serialization, jackson, nested, xmlmapper

I have a problem with Jackson to serialize nested object.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "A")
public class A {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String Iee;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "B")
    private B b;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "B")
public class B {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String Jee;
}
```

When i serialize the Object A created like that :

```
final B b = new B("attribute B value");
final A a = new A("attribute A value", b);
final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
final String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(a);
```

I want this result :

```
<A Iee="attribute A value">
    <B Jee="attribute B value" />
</A>
```

But i got this :

```
<A Iee="attribute A value">
    <B Jee="attribute B value">
        <Jee>attribute B value</Jee>
    </B>
</A>
```

I search but i didn't found anything about that on google.
Any idea ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

i found the error.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "B")
public class B {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String jee;
}
```

When Jee begin by a caps, it doesn't work.
When jee begin by a lower case, it works.

Answer (score 1):

It is working with javafollowing maven's dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```